# Please help write a Test Class for method for object UserRecordAccess (read only object i think)

Tags: code-coverage

Controller class

```
    public class Redirectcomp{
      public String sCaseId {get;set;}
      public Redirectcomp(){
      }
      public PageReference autorun() {
        sCaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        if(sCaseId != null && sCaseId != '') {
          List<UserRecordAccess> lstUserAccess = [SELECT HasEditAccess,RecordId  FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND RecordId =: sCaseId ];
  ---->      if(lstUserAccess.size()>0) {
            UserRecordAccess sInstance =lstUserAccess.get(0);
            IF(sInstance.HasEditAccess == true  && sCaseId != null ){
              PageReference redirect= new PageReference('/apex/compreport_2?id='+sCaseId );
              redirect.setRedirect(true);  
              return redirect;
            }
            else{
              PageReference redirect= new PageReference('/apex/LimitedAccess' );
              redirect.setRedirect(true); 
              return redirect;
            }
          }
        } ---------->
        return null;
      }
    }
```

My test class with 50% code coverage. I am finding it difficult as i don't know much about  UserRecordAccess object

```
@isTest

private class Redirectcomp_test {
  static testmethod void RedirectcompTests() { 
    Account acc = new Account(name = 'brijender');
    insert acc;
    contact oCon = new contact(lastname = 'Singh', accountid = acc.id);
    insert oCon;
    Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Pre-Employ Portal - Vendors (lvl 1) Partial']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 't23', Email='teststandarduser@stemcell.com', 
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Compliance', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = userProfile.Id,
    ContactId = oCon.id,
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='teststandarduser@stemcell.com');
    insert u;
    system.runas(u) {
      PageReference pr;      
      Redirectcomp  oRedirectcomp = new Redirectcomp();
      apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id','test');
      pr = oRedirectcomp.autorun();

    }  

  }  

}
```

Comment: What block of code is not getting covered?

Comment: @ RedDevil - block is marked that is not getting covered by test class.Best part about the controller class is that you can copy and save ot in your salesforce account as well and  can do testing on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 things from your code

1. You are setting caseid to test and querying that in your test class but a case with id test will never exist. you need to insert a case and send that id to your method for you to execute that code block
2. You also need to ensure the profile has some sharing mechanism setup to access the case or else the user will not have access to the case